# Can this code be condensed or simplified?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

What's a simpler way to write something repetitive like this?

For expedience at work I often do things in quick, copy & paste fashion because I know it will work, and don't have the time research the "right" way to do it.

(The IDs could be changed to work with a loop):

```
// OPEN PRIVACY
$("#privacy_trigger").click(function() {
$("#privacy").fadeIn(150);
positionPopup();
});

//CLOSE PRIVACY
$("#close_privacy").click(function () {
$("#privacy").fadeOut(150);
});

//OPEN TERMS
$("#terms_trigger").click(function() {
$("#terms").fadeIn(150);
positionPopup();
});

//CLOSE TERMS
$("#close_terms").click(function () {
$("#terms").fadeOut(150);
});

//OPEN PARTICIPATION
$("#participation_trigger").click(function() {
$("#participation").fadeIn(150);
positionPopup();
});

//CLOSE PARTICIPATION
$("#close_participation").click(function () {
$("#participation").fadeOut(150);
});
```

Comment: "don't have the time research the "right" way to do it" -- It's one thing to ask for help because you don't know how to do something.  It's entirely another to ask a community to do your work for you because you're admittedly just too lazy to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot....

```
$('[id$="_trigger"]').click(function() {
   var newId = $(this).attr('id').replace('_trigger', '');
   $('#'+newId ).fadeIn(150);
   positionPopup();
});

$('[id^="close_"]').click(function() {
   var newId = $(this).attr('id').replace('close_', '');
   $('#'+newId ).fadeOut(150);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ted... worked perfectly!